# How to Upgrade Python 3.5 to 3.10 on Debian 9 Correctly?

Tags: debian, apt, python

I have a Python web app that uses Django.

The production server is running Debian 9 and has Python 3.5.3 installed.

I have tried to upgrade it incorrectly.  This led to a major defect in the server's kernel (Panic Kernel). After getting error 503 Connection Timeout from the server, I can no longer connect to the server in any way. Is it possible for me to upgrade Python to 3.10 on Debian 9?

I ran this command:

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

This was the result:

```
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:4 https://repos-droplet.digitalocean.com/apt/droplet-agent main InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian stretch Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
7 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
mysql-client mysql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to upgrade Python from 3.5 to 3.10 using `apt`.  The reason is that `python3.5` and `python3.10` are two different programs.  For Debian 9, the version of Python that corresponds to the `python3` package is 3.5.

I recommend [downloading](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-31011/) and building the Python 3.10 source.  You can then create a virtual environment for your project.

Comment: If I reinstall Python again will I need to configure my server settings again? Will the server be affected by that or not?

Comment: Impossible to tell given the information you’ve provided.  You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Don't manually install python3.10 globally. Use a `venv` for your django app to keep things isolated.